# Is there an idiom that means "one cunning person always can be outsmarted (tricked) by another"?

Tags: expressions, idioms

I'm looking for an idiom (or other fixed expression) meaning that when there is one cunning person who thinks much of himself, there will be another one who can outsmart him.

Answer (score 5):

"Poetic justice", "Taste of your own medicine",

From [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/outfox)

> Outfox

Verb: beat through cleverness and wit, outdo someone in trickery

From [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/play+(one)+at+(one%27s)+own+game)

> Play someone at their own game

If you play someone at their own game, you treat them in the same unfair or unpleasant way that they have been treating you. It used to annoy me when clients came in the office and my colleagues didn't introduce us. Now I play them at their own game and when my clients come and see me, I don't introduce them either.

Also from [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/turn+the+tables+on+(one))

> Turn the tables on (one)

To change or reverse something dramatically against an opponent or adversary. Wow, they really turned the tables on their opponents after the intermission. The score went from 0-3 to 5-3!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Do I have to provide links? Is it mandatory? What about commonly occurring phrases that everyone knows of?

Comment: Hi TheGreat, not everyone may know them, hence the question.  It also helps to give examples of these phrases in use from the sources you find.

Comment: Thank you @livresque for editing my answer and your helpful comment.

Comment: The obvious answer is *outfox* (+1), but you should still expand on it somewhat; *cunning* and *outwit* are in its definition.

Comment: Thank you @HippoSawrUs. I have added definition of "outfox".

Answer (score 4):

> **There's always a bigger fish.** [Proverb]
>
> No matter how large or intimidating a person or thing is, there is
> likely to be an even larger or more intimidating person or thing
> somewhere.

[[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/there%27s_always_a_bigger_fish)]

> The bigger fish idea is that no matter how intelligent, how smart, or
> how much you know, there is always someone who can top that.

[[Bernadette Gray; Quora](https://www.quora.com/Where-did-the-proverb-Theres-always-a-bigger-fish-come-from)]

Comment: This one most accurately conveys the idea I had in mind. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a related idiom, from [Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Set+a+thief+to+catch+a+thief)

> **Set a thief to catch a thief.**
>
> The best person to catch a thief is another thief, because he or she knows how thieves think.

Answer (score 0):

It's a quote attributed to Macchiavelli.

[image]

It is double pleasure to deceive the deceiver—Niccolò Machiavelli

Comment: Why the need to post an image of a quote? And a huge one at that.